# React Bootstrap Navbar error: <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I got this error:

> Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<a>` cannot appear as a descendant of `<a>`.

```
       <Navbar expand="lg" variant="dark" bg='header'>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <NavLink className="navbar-brand navbar-brand--img" to="/">
              <img src={logo} alt="Logo"/>
            </NavLink>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ms-auto">
                  <Nav.Link>
                    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/check">Check</NavLink>
                  </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link>
                    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeClassName="active" to="/template">Template</NavLink>
                  </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid HTML to have an anchor inside an anchor, and therefore it's invalid React to have a `NavLink` component inside a `Nav.Link` component. They both result in anchor elements being rendered.

If you review [the Navbar docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) you'll see that your markup varies from what's suggested.